# Indicative tooltip + info tooltip over the same element

Tags: interaction-design, web-app, tables, tooltips

I have a table that contains some items texts the user can click to filter by those values. 
For example, if they click on the username, only rows containing that username will be shown on the table.

This is a similar behavior to what Github does on it [issues forum](https://github.com/strongloop/expressjs.com/issues). So you can filter by the person who opened the issue and so on.

Now, the problem comes when I need to display extra information on the tooltip. This time, instead of an indicative of the action of clicking, I would need to add extra information about the text itself. For example, if I'm the user ID, the tooltip should show the username as well.
Or if its a name, a description of it.

How can I deal with this idea of two tooltips for the same element?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to display the tip with a title and description, I would suggest trying to use a *"super tooltip,"* or in another term, a *"popover."* These items will allow you to have a larger area to have a clear title "Filter by {item}" and a short description to give any additional help to what they will be filtering.

http://www.nngroup.com/articles/best-application-designs/
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

I would prefer this route over using multiple tooltips at the same time, as the popup keeps the content organized and focused on the item you are trying to filter, so there is no possibility of confusion as to what the tooltip is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add an additional tooltip alongside those items that have explanatory information?

[image]

That way the user knows that some fields have additional information associated to them, and is able to select the respective one accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you could write the tooltip in such a way that if the username filter is on operation then the tooltip displays the name along with the tip and if not that part of the tooltip remains blank:

pseudo code

```
tooltipText = "filter by this"
filteredTip = "filtered by: "
if the filterStatus is set (if a user has clicked/touched a column value which is filterable)
AND
if that value is == userName

tooltipText = filteredTip + userName
```

a more generic solution could be achieved

```
filterName = colValFilterName

tooltipText = filteredTip + filterName
```

so if the column were date the filtered tool tip would say

> filtered by: date

and if the username column

> filtered by: user name

Comment: Not what I want. "Filter by" should be there always. Then, additionally some extra information about the text itself has to be shown. For example `UK (filter by this - United Kingdom)`

Comment: @OP: Ok, perhaps it's not what you want but once a column has been filtered then it isn't grammatically correct to continue to say filter by on that value. On the unfiltered values, then yes no problem but a filtered value should say "filtered by" in my opinion. I also think a colour change to the label text would give an immediate visual context and would add ui/ux value, perhaps even simply "bolding" the filtered **9MI** would suffice when it is clicked and there is no reason why the additional info isn't concatenated on to the end --> filtered by: **9MI** - user since 2006, 20 posts (etc)

Comment: I think you still dont get the idea. I want something like "UK" `(filter by UK - United Kingdom, Europe)`.

UK is the word I want to filter by, then the extra information is `United Kingdom, Europe`